# Hashmap para traer toda la lista

Tags: java, hashmap

Un compañero me puso como objetivo armar una lista de pacientes, tras lograrlo con un `list-arraylist` me sugiere hacer lo mismo con un `hashmap` dándome como pista esto: `Map<List<Pacientes>,Integer>`

Probé varias combinaciones en base a lo que entendí de lo que leí y me trabe sin saber cómo continuar. ¿Podrían ayudarme, por favor?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<List<Pacientes>,Integer>

    Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente("Rodolfo","Fernandez","32.265.887","4549-2250", new Domicilio("Nazca",2253,"Villa Pueyrredon",1432));
    Paciente paciente2 = new Paciente("Monica","Perez","34.221.189","4529-0458", new Domicilio("Nazarre",239,"Villa Adelina",1451));
    Paciente paciente3 = new Paciente("Ada","Hernandez","32.265.887","4542-2126", new Domicilio("Juramento",6258,"Villa Bosch",1816));
    Paciente paciente4 = new Paciente("Lucian","Greymark","32.265.887","4523-1140", new Domicilio("Triunvirato",4751,"Villa Urquiza",1431));

    lista.add(paciente1);
    lista.add(paciente2);
    lista.add(paciente3);
    lista.add(paciente4);

    System.out.println( "Lista de Pacientes");
        System.out.println(paciente.toString());
    }

}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué se supone que tienes que hacer con el Map? ¿Guardar los pacientes por nombre? Edita la pregunta con esos detalles.

Comment: Para temas específicos usa la documentación oficial.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave del `HashMap` se utilizará para almacenar una lista de pacientes y el valor se utilizará para almacenar la cantidad de pacientes en esa lista.

Aquí te muestro cómo podrías implementar esta idea en tu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<List<Paciente>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<Paciente> pacientes1 = new ArrayList<>();
    pacientes1.add(new Paciente("Rodolfo","Fernandez","32.265.887","4549-2250", new Domicilio("Nazca",2253,"Villa Pueyrredon",1432)));
    pacientes1.add(new Paciente("Monica","Perez","34.221.189","4529-0458", new Domicilio("Nazarre",239,"Villa Adelina",1451)));
    map.put(pacientes1, pacientes1.size());

    List<Paciente> pacientes2 = new ArrayList<>();
    pacientes2.add(new Paciente("Ada","Hernandez","32.265.887","4542-2126", new Domicilio("Juramento",6258,"Villa Bosch",1816)));
    pacientes2.add(new Paciente("Lucian","Greymark","32.265.887","4523-1140", new Domicilio("Triunvirato",4751,"Villa Urquiza",1431)));
    map.put(pacientes2, pacientes2.size());

    System.out.println("Mapa de Pacientes:");
    for (List<Paciente> pacientes : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(pacientes.toString() + " - Cantidad: " + map.get(pacientes));
    }
}
```

Creamos un nuevo `HashMap` llamado `map`. Luego creamos dos listas de pacientes y las agregamos al mapa utilizando el método `put`. El valor que asignamos a cada clave es simplemente el tamaño de la lista.

Finalmente, iteramos a través del mapa y mostramos la lista de pacientes y la cantidad de pacientes en cada lista.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tu respuesta fue la mas apropiada para el caso del ejercicio ^^

Answer (score 0):

La idea detrás de la clase `Map`, es contener datos con una clave y un valor asociado, la clave debe ser única, para poder invocar a un paciente inequívocamente, por ejemplo en tu caso, se podría usar el número de paciente (o DNI) de la siguiente forma:

```
// DNI -- objeto Paciente  
12345678 -> Paciente
```

Una vez cargado el paciente en el `Map`, para obtener sus datos, usamos el método `get` del mismo.

```
Map<Integer, Paciente> lista = new HashMap<>();

   Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente( "Rodolfo", "Fernandez", "32.265.887", "4549-2250", new Domicilio( "Nazca", 2253, "Villa Pueyrredon", 1432 ) );
   Paciente paciente2 = new Paciente( "Monica", "Perez", "34.221.189", "4529-0458", new Domicilio( "Nazarre", 239, "Villa Adelina", 1451 ) );
   Paciente paciente3 = new Paciente( "Ada", "Hernandez", "32.265.887", "4542-2126", new Domicilio( "Juramento", 6258, "Villa Bosch", 1816 ) );
   Paciente paciente4 = new Paciente( "Lucian", "Greymark", "32.265.887", "4523-1140", new Domicilio( "Triunvirato", 4751, "Villa Urquiza", 1431 ) );

   lista.put( 10000000, paciente1 );
   lista.put( 20000000, paciente2 );
   lista.put( 30000000, paciente3 );
   lista.put( 40000000, paciente4 );

   int numneroPaciente = 10000000;
   System.out.println( "Lista de Pacientes" );
   System.out.println( lista.get( numneroPaciente ).toString() );
}
```

Si deseas usar como `key` algo que no sea un `Integer` (por ejemplo un numero de paciente con formato "12-345"), declaras el `Map` así:

```
Map<String, Paciente> lista = new HashMap<>();
```

y le cargas el paciente...

```
lista.put( "12-345", paciente1 );
```

y si el numero de paciente o DNI, está contenido en paciente...

```
lista.put( paciente1.getDNI(), paciente1 );
```